# Add quotation marks to JSON Object attributes

Tags: javascript, json

How do I add quotation marks to a JSON Object attributes for example like this:

```
{name:"User 01"}
```

so it should look like that afterward:

```
{"name":"User 01"}
```

***both of them are strings***

Comment: Where are you seeing the first example?  Javascript Object?

Comment: shift + 2, name, shift + 2... or have a missed the question?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It's the same thing.

Comment: No it is not, the first is not valid JSON.

Comment: It's the same thing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify(eval('{name:"User 01"}'));
```

Not really great but works.

Comment: Uhh, eval.. I don't like that, but anyway, that is exactly what I wanted! Thanks dude!

Comment: Jep, don't like it either but keeps you going until you find something better. Best practice is to add FIXME as a comment above. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the first example is a Javascript object, you could convert it into a JSON string using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify({name:"User 01"});
```

outputs: `"{"name":"User 01"}"`

### Assuming String

If the first example is a string, I think you would have to parse through it with methods like `split`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not write it down; The important thing is, it is not a JSON object, it is a string, which is the output from JSON.stringify-ed JSON Object and the quotation marks from the attributes were deleted

Comment: Parsing via split is tricky if you want do it right, I.e. strings could contain colons or commas...

Answer (score 3):

the first notation

```
var string = {name:"user 01"}
```

if you use it  then you can directly access all the properties and methods of the string object

but if you use this notation :

```
var string = {"name":"user 01"}
```

then you have to use :

```
window.JSON.parse("'"+string+"'")
```

**Update:**
Now that we have ES6, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) :

```
window.JSON.parse(`'${string}'`)
```

in order to access all the methods and properties of string object

the last notation is used generally when getting data back from php script 
or something like that

Comment: What JS implementation are you using that doesn't like `var obj = { "name": "user 01" }`? That's a perfectly-valid JS object literal.. the quotation marks around the key are optional if the key is a valid identifier, but always acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
function JSONify(obj){
  var o = {};
  for(var i in obj){
    o['"'+i+'"'] = obj[i]; // make the quotes
  }
  return o;
}
console.log(JSONify({name:'User 01'}));
```